# How to let user decide how many decimal places they want printed in their float?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

How would I make a program allow the user to choose how many decimal spaces they would like to see printed in their float value?

For example, the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float x;
    x = 0.67183377;
    printf("%.2f\n", x);
}
```

Would give us an output of `0.67`.But what if the user wanted to see the full number, or up to the fourth decimal place, for example. How would they do this?

Comment: See [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html): `printf("%.*f\n", n, x);` where `n` is an `int` that contains the number of decimal places to be printed.  Note that a `float` can only really hold about 6-7 decimal digits; the 8th and 9th ones in the example will be largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) for the details.  Use:

```
printf("%.*f\n", n, x);
```

where `n` is an `int` that contains the number of decimal places to be printed.  Note that a `float` can only really hold about 6-7 decimal digits; the 8th one in the example will be largely irrelevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x = 0.67183377;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        printf("%.*f\n", n, x);
    return(0);
}
```

Example output:

```
1
0.7
0.67
0.672
0.6718
0.67183
0.671834
0.6718338
0.67183375
0.671833754
```

The value is converted to a `double` before it is passed to `printf()` because that happens with all variadic functions.  When `x` is changed to a `double`, the output is:

```
1
0.7
0.67
0.672
0.6718
0.67183
0.671834
0.6718338
0.67183377
0.671833770
```